# How to create a script that will find all numbers in range(0,100) that can be divided by 4?

Tags: python

How to create program that will print all numbers in range(0,100) that  can be divide by 4. And how to use  `x%4` (x is variable)?

I tried this:

```
for x in range(100):
    if x%4 == 0:
        print(x)
        break
```

Comment: What is the point of `break`??

Comment: Do you want to print _all_ such numbers? If so, why are you exiting the loop as soon as you find the first one (which is zero)?

Comment: Just remove the `break`, and you will get the answer

Comment: I what to loop finish when all numbers <100 are printed.

Comment: THen do not break :/

Comment: `range(0, 100, 4)`?

Comment: `[i for i in range(100) if i % 4 == 0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, just remove the `break` and it works:

```
for x in range(100):
      if x%4 == 0:
          print(x)
```

The `break` command is meant to stop a `for` loop before exhaustion of the list it is looping over, see e.g. [break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops). So your `break` stopped the loop as soon as you found the first number divisible by 4, ie zero.

If you want something more compact, either of these work too:

```
print [x for x in range(100) if x%4 == 0]
print range(0, 100, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

`break` is used for stopping entirely the current loop. So there, it will only print `0`, and stop the loop. You don't need it in your case.